# Android: Enable/Disable Auto Sync and Background Data

Tags: android, synchronization, gprs

I want to develop an application that disables the Background Data (new feature in Android 1.5) and Auto Sync and then enables GPRS/EDGE connection and vice versa.

I figured out how to enable/disable GPRS/EDGE by changing the APN settings. (weird solution. However; Android developers couldn't think a user may want to disable GPRS/EDGE) But, I couldn't find a way to enable/disable Auto Sync and Background data.

I investigated the Android code and as I understood, the Sync operation is an intent. So, I wanted to reach with putExtra to the intent and trigger the enabling/disabling. But; I couldn't find the correct keyword. Or maybe I was totally wrong.

What is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my HTC dreams, there is a checkbox to disable the auto sync. I can look for the menu arborescence if you wish so you can find what the callback function is in the Android source code. But I am pretty sure auto sync cannot be completely disabled. Unchecking auto sync will prevent sync from being performed on a timed basis, but it will occur everytime you run an app with sync capabilities if any network data connection is available.

Good luck anyway.

EDIT :

There are two ways to get the info you desire.

First, I think you can use the code in android-sources/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/Utils.java to create an activity that will enlist all the keys of the intent then find the one you want.

The other way is to write a nice mail to the guy who made the Toggle Setting app (http://smartphoneandroid.com/2008/12/28/toggle-setting-perfect-app-for-android-phone.html) since he obviously found a solution to your problem. His email address is written in the app sheet on the android market. I won't write it here, but if you do not have access to real android phone, I can mail it to you on your mail address.

Comment: If you can find the callback function, I will be very happy. I dig for this information. However; I couldn't find anything. 

On the other hand, I know that I can not prevent the third party applications to use GPRS/EDGE. But, my main aim is to disable the sync with Google server only. Because; As I observed if auto sync is on, Google sync uses most of my data plan.

Answer (score 2):

Background data is a [secure setting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html), so cannot be changed by user applications. But bear in mind, it's just a setting - it's not enforced. Apps are meant to read it and respect it but I bet some don't.

Comment: If I can find out to disable auto sync only, Background Data may not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

To Disable the AutoSynch

```
ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(false);
```

To Enable the AutoSynch

```
ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true);
```

Permission you require is

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

setMasterSyncAutomatically() on ContentResolver should do it. Check: [general-sync-settings-auto-sync-checkbox-programtically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009273/general-sync-settings-auto-sync-checkbox-programtically)