# general sync settings "auto-sync" checkbox programmatically

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am looking for a way to enable/disable the "auto-sync" checkbox in the "general sync settings".

Afair the stock power control widget has this feature too. If this widget can do, there should be a solution for me too, right? Please guys help me out, I am desperately looking for a solution on the web with no success.

Is it possible that a user interaction is mandatory for this operation? I know I can send an Intent to open the Sync View but this is not my intention!

I am not looking for the sync settings for a specific account as I found in this forum like

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(Account account, String authority, boolean sync);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am looking for a way to enable/disable the "auto-sync" checkbox in the "general sync settings".

**UPDATE**

Try `setMasterSyncAutomatically()` on `ContentResolver`.

Comment: I am afraid to tell but what you wrote cannot be correct. There is a widget in the Android market by curvefish that does exactly the thing I wanted to do. It enables the auto sync feature without user interaction and it is not part of the firmware! So there must be a way to implement this. I've already written an email to the developer to find out.

Comment: @GZA: Ah, but you pointed out what might be the right area to look -- see replaced answer above.

Comment: How to listen in a BroadcastReceiver (onReceive) ether Auto-sync data is turning on/off ?

Comment: It does not work on Android 9 (MIUI 11), Xiaomi Mi6

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true); // enables AutoSync
```

You should also add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: It does not work on Android 9 (MIUI 11), Xiaomi Mi6