# How can I enable sync with on{x}

Tags: android, onx

Is there a way to turn on/off Sync with [on{x}](https://www.onx.ms) scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [on{x} documentation](https://www.onx.ms/#apiPage/network), no.

You can turn on/off mobile data usage, using `mobileDataEnabled(get; set;)` but that's probably not what you're looking for.

Actually, on second thought, you could write a native Android app that would receive a custom intent and toggle the sync setting, and then call that from on{x} using `launch(String appName, Object params, Object callback)`. See [the applications section](https://www.onx.ms/#apiPage/applications) of the on{x} docs for more on this.

...and [general sync settings "auto-sync" checkbox programtically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009273/general-sync-settings-auto-sync-checkbox-programtically) may help you with making such a native app.