# Toggle on auto-sync progarammatically in Android

Tags: android

May be this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767771/android-enable-disable-auto-sync-and-background-data) is asked about 2-4 year ago.Still m not satisfied.My problem is: "how to turn on/off auto Sync Programmatically".I dont want any specific data to synchronous.Just want to know Is that possible to enable or disable Auto-sync programmatically ? If possible, then How? Can anyone give me Example?

which is shown like this on Android Screen: 
[image]

What is the use of `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);` in auto-sync?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about gmail auto sync the email right ? One way is setMasterSyncAutomatically() (ContentResolver), applies to all the accounts (and providers). If you set this off/false you can disable all the syncs.

This is what we have from android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setMasterSyncAutomatically%28boolean%29).

```
public static void setMasterSyncAutomatically (boolean sync)

Added in API level 5
Sets the master auto-sync setting that applies to all the providers and accounts. If this is false then the per-provider auto-sync setting is ignored.

This method requires the caller to hold the permission WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS.

Parameters
sync    the master auto-sync setting that applies to all the providers and accounts
```

Comment: ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true); is it like this?..so i need to add only this line in my Class?

Comment: frankly its a rude practice to change settings programmatically you should ask for permission from the user before you do so.

Comment: go ahead and try it out, it should work. To test it ensure that you switch off all sync before you run your app.

Comment: It does not help