# Enable auto sync programmatically

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter, android-account

I want to enable auto sync in account settings in my app programmatically. I've set up the SyncAdapter, declared it in manifest, I added account and after this action I tried:

```java
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);
ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true);
```

but it's not working. There is the same questions on SE:

- [Android how to enable/disable auto sync programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5138256/3422245)
- [general sync settings "auto-sync" checkbox programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8009273/3422245)
- [Toggle on auto-sync progarammatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17489799/3422245)
- [general sync settings "auto-sync" checkbox programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8009273/3422245)

but they are too old, and in them I found, that I need to use `ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true)`, but it's not working on my Android 7, Android 9.

[image: Auto sync is not enabled]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255360/6645076

Comment: @Crazo7924 thanks, I do it, all this tips already written in my codebase, but auto sync switcher in the app account settings does not enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the `authority` string argument in `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true);`, it needs to be `"com.android.contacts"` for contacts synchronization